# Visual Studio - SQLConnection not working on an SQL Server Express database

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to connect to an SQL Express database I have created as a `.mdf` file. The database is named `PruebaDB.mdf` and appears in the Data Connections section of the Server Explorer window:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVLsf.jpg

It's data source is set to "Microsoft SQL Server Database File (SqlClient)"

This is my code:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

    Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim connectionString As String = GetConnectionString()
        Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
            connection.Open()
            'do other things after open works
        End Using
    End Sub


    Private Function GetConnectionString() As String
        Return "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFileName=C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\Apuestas\Apuestas\PruebaDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
    End Function

    End Class
```

When I click the button, however, I get an exception (translated from Spanish):

> Error related to the network or specific to the instance while establishing connection to the SQL Server server. Server was not found or is not accessible. Check that the instance name is correct and SQL Server is configured to admit remote connections.

What would be the problem? How can I connect to my database?

If I'm doing something wrong, how can I do a simple local database in Visual Studio (basic) for my project?

Comment: your connectionstring is for localdb, not for sql server express. Is your question about localdb or about sql server ?

Comment: create a text file and give it extension `.UDL` Then doubleclick on it. You now get a form where you can build and test a connectionstring. When it works, open the file in notepad and find the correct connectionstring there

Comment: Apparently in localdb? I'm not even sure. I've made the .UDL file but I don't know which provider should I chose. My purpose is to just make a local database to work for my project.

Comment: for localdb you do not need sql server express, you should google for the localdb drivers.